Prevent NSTableView from responding to keyDown:
I have an NSTableView that doesn't allow selecting rows. I'd like keyDown: events (edit: from arrow keys) to reach the view's controller (which is also its delegate).
By default, a table view "consumes" these events, so they don't go up the responder chain.
How can I prevent that, preferably without subclassing NSTableView?

NSTableView does send unused keyDown events to the next responder. What are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you want to subclass NSTableView?

As the table view shows the selected content of a source list (another view), the arrows keys should navigate the source list, even if the focus is on the table view (trust me, it makes sense UI-wise).  I can subclass if there is no simpler alternative.

Usually the key events are sent to the focused UI element. There is no simple way to change that.
